# Can you use Elgato's HDMIComponent Game Capture HD as a video-in device in C#?

Tags: video, video-streaming, video-capture

We're wondering if it's possible to capture the video stream from Elgato's Game Capture HD (or something similar--the model/brand doesn't matter) and get it in a window using C#.  We haven't found any information on using that product with anything but its own software, nor have we found any other hardware that can capture such a thing.

Again, our goal is simply to get a device with Component Out to appear in a window on-screen, nothing else.  No recording, no screen capture, no overlays, nothing.  Just pure, 'live' video.

Been looking for several months now and getting nowhere so I figured I'd throw this out to the SO community.

Answer (score 0):

Look for registered video capture DirectShow filters, you can load it by its GUID. It'll be installed when Game Capture HD 1.2.1 is installed. Contact Elgato support with questions.

Comment: I did contact their level II support... twice... to the same tune of 'Our hardware will *only* work with our software.' I also asked about an API and even tried to back-door some info as an aside to another question but no dice their either.  I'm hoping they just don't support it but it does work.  Are you saying you know from experience you can use their device as a HD capture using the methods you describe here, or are you just speculating based on other video capture devices?  If the former, can you provide any example code?  Again, we just want a live video feed, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/elgatosf/gamecapture/tree/master/VideoCaptureFilterSample) Github project. It seems to show how to use Elgato's Game Capture HD as a capture device in a c++ DirectShow application. The same method should apply to a c# project.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but in case anyone else stumbles across it it is quite easy to use the video stream from an Elgato capture card in C# with DirectShow. Here is an example of creating a simple graph and previewing the Elgato's video stream.

```cs
using DirectShowLib;

DsROTEntry rot; //Used for remotely connecting to graph

IFilterGraph2 graph;
ICaptureGraphBuilder2 captureGraph;
IBaseFilter elgatoFilter;
IBaseFilter smartTeeFilter;
IBaseFilter videoRendererFilter;
Size videoSize;

//Set the video size to use for capture and recording
videoSize = new Size(1280, 720);

//Initialize filter graph and capture graph
graph = (IFilterGraph2)new FilterGraph();
captureGraph = (ICaptureGraphBuilder2)new CaptureGraphBuilder2();
captureGraph.SetFiltergraph(graph);
rot = new DsROTEntry(graph);

//Create filter for Elgato
Guid elgatoGuid = new Guid("39F50F4C-99E1-464A-B6F9-D605B4FB5918");
Type comType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(elgatoGuid);
elgatoFilter = (IBaseFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(comType);
graph.AddFilter(elgatoFilter, "Elgato Video Capture Filter");

//Create smart tee filter, add to graph, connect Elgato's video out to smart tee in
smartTeeFilter = (IBaseFilter)new SmartTee();
graph.AddFilter(smartTeeFilter, "Smart Tee");
IPin outPin = GetPin(PinDirection.Output, "Video", elgatoFilter);
IPin inPin = GetPin(PinDirection.Input, smartTeeFilter);
graph.Connect(outPin, inPin);

//Create video renderer filter, add it to graph, connect smartTee Preview pin to video renderer's input pin
videoRendererFilter = (IBaseFilter)new VideoRenderer();
graph.AddFilter(videoRendererFilter, "Video Renderer");
outPin = GetPin(PinDirection.Output, "Preview", smartTeeFilter);
inPin = GetPin(PinDirection.Input, videoRendererFilter);
graph.Connect(outPin, inPin);

//Render stream from video renderer
captureGraph.RenderStream(PinCategory.Preview, MediaType.Video, videoRendererFilter, null, null);

//Set the video preview to be the videoFeed panel
IVideoWindow vw = (IVideoWindow)graph;
vw.put_Owner(videoFeed.Handle);
vw.put_MessageDrain(this.Handle);
vw.put_WindowStyle(WindowStyle.Child | WindowStyle.ClipSiblings | WindowStyle.ClipChildren);
vw.SetWindowPosition(0, 0, 1280, 720);

//Start the preview
mediaControl = graph as IMediaControl;
mediaControl.Run();

private IPin GetPin(PinDirection pinDir, IBaseFilter filter)
{
    IEnumPins epins;
    int hr = filter.EnumPins(out epins);
    if (hr < 0)
        return null;
    IntPtr fetched = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(4);
    IPin[] pins = new IPin[1];
    epins.Reset();
    while (epins.Next(1, pins, fetched) == 0)
    {
        PinInfo pinfo;
        pins[0].QueryPinInfo(out pinfo);
        bool found = (pinfo.dir == pinDir);
        DsUtils.FreePinInfo(pinfo);
        if (found)
            return pins[0];
    }
    return null;
}

private IPin GetPin(PinDirection pinDir, string name, IBaseFilter filter)
{
    IEnumPins epins;
    int hr = filter.EnumPins(out epins);
    if (hr < 0)
        return null;
    IntPtr fetched = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(4);
    IPin[] pins = new IPin[1];
    epins.Reset();
    while (epins.Next(1, pins, fetched) == 0)
    {
        PinInfo pinfo;
        pins[0].QueryPinInfo(out pinfo);
        bool found = (pinfo.dir == pinDir && pinfo.name == name);
        DsUtils.FreePinInfo(pinfo);
        if (found)
            return pins[0];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Roman what is GetPin i can't find this method ? And what is the variable rot in the line: rot = new DsROTEntry(graph); rot not exist. I'm getting errors that GetPin and rot not exist.

Comment: I agree with @Simon's comment in that this code doesn't appear to be complete. Simon, can you comment or elaborate further?