# How can i use DirectShowLib to capture the elgato video stream window?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, directshow

I have elgato capture  device connected to my pc and i'm trying to capture and watch live the window of the elgato capture device.

I searched in google and found this answer:

[Can you use Elgato's HDMIComponent Game Capture HD as a video-in device in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370125/can-you-use-elgatos-hdmicomponent-game-capture-hd-as-a-video-in-device-in-c)

This is the code:

```
IFilterGraph2 graph;
ICaptureGraphBuilder2 captureGraph;
IBaseFilter elgatoFilter;
IBaseFilter smartTeeFilter;
IBaseFilter videoRendererFilter;
Size videoSize;

//Set the video size to use for capture and recording
videoSize = new Size(1280, 720);

//Initialize filter graph and capture graph
graph = (IFilterGraph2)new FilterGraph();
captureGraph = (ICaptureGraphBuilder2)new CaptureGraphBuilder2();
captureGraph.SetFiltergraph(graph);
rot = new DsROTEntry(graph);

//Create filter for Elgato
Guid elgatoGuid = new Guid("39F50F4C-99E1-464A-B6F9-D605B4FB5918");
Type comType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(elgatoGuid);
elgatoFilter = (IBaseFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(comType);
graph.AddFilter(elgatoFilter, "Elgato Video Capture Filter");

//Create smart tee filter, add to graph, connect Elgato's video out to smart tee in
smartTeeFilter = (IBaseFilter)new SmartTee();
graph.AddFilter(smartTeeFilter, "Smart Tee");
IPin outPin = GetPin(PinDirection.Output, "Video", elgatoFilter);
IPin inPin = GetPin(PinDirection.Input, smartTeeFilter);
graph.Connect(outPin, inPin);

//Create video renderer filter, add it to graph, connect smartTee Preview pin to video renderer's input pin
videoRendererFilter = (IBaseFilter)new VideoRenderer();
graph.AddFilter(videoRendererFilter, "Video Renderer");
outPin = GetPin(PinDirection.Output, "Preview", smartTeeFilter);
inPin = GetPin(PinDirection.Input, videoRendererFilter);
graph.Connect(outPin, inPin);

//Render stream from video renderer
captureGraph.RenderStream(PinCategory.Preview, MediaType.Video, videoRendererFilter, null, null);

//Set the video preview to be the videoFeed panel
IVideoWindow vw = (IVideoWindow)graph;
vw.put_Owner(videoFeed.Handle);
vw.put_MessageDrain(this.Handle);
vw.put_WindowStyle(WindowStyle.Child | WindowStyle.ClipSiblings | WindowStyle.ClipChildren);
vw.SetWindowPosition(0, 0, 1280, 720);

//Start the preview
mediaControl = graph as IMediaControl;
mediaControl.Run();
```

I created a new form in my project and added the DirectShowLib-2005 dll
Then i added in the top of the new form:

```
using DirectShowLib;
```

Before the constructor added the global vars:

```
IFilterGraph2 graph;
ICaptureGraphBuilder2 captureGraph;
IBaseFilter elgatoFilter;
IBaseFilter smartTeeFilter;
IBaseFilter videoRendererFilter;
Size videoSize;
```

Then in the constructor i added the rest of the code.
And i'm getting now few errors:

On this line the variable rot is not exist:

```
rot = new DsROTEntry(graph);
```

In the four lines that use the method GetPin so the method GetPin not exist:

```
IPin outPin = GetPin(PinDirection.Output, "Video", elgatoFilter);
IPin inPin = GetPin(PinDirection.Input, smartTeeFilter);
outPin = GetPin(PinDirection.Output, "Preview", smartTeeFilter);
inPin = GetPin(PinDirection.Input, videoRendererFilter);
```

On this line:

```
vw.put_Owner(videoFeed.Handle);
```

The variable videoFeed not exist.

And in the end this two lines:

```
mediaControl = graph as IMediaControl;
mediaControl.Run();
```

mediaControl not exist.

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`videoFeed` is your control which is to host video you are embedding.

`mediaControl` would be a variable of type `IMediaControl`:

```
IMediaControl mediaControl = graph as IMediaControl;
mediaControl.Run();
```

---

`GetPin` is [this](http://forum.infognition.com/index.php?topic=46.0) or similar; `DsROTEntry` is not mandatory but [helps inspect filter graph externally](http://duanenewman.net/blog/post/2011/09/14/Attaching-to-external-DirectShow-graphs-using-Graph-Edit.aspx) using GraphEdit or similar tool.

Comment: Roman what about the method GetPin ? And do i need this rot variable ? rot = new DsROTEntry(graph); i don't see any use of it later in the code. rot also not exist.

Comment: Tried it. The update above. In the link you gave i tried the GetPin method so in my code i changed in all places i got error GetPin not exist to: GetPin(elgatoFilter, "Video"); but now i'm getting two errors inside the GetPin method i took from the link: checkHR method is not exist.

Comment: Ok managed to fix errors running but nothing. My elgato software i can see the ps4 window but with my program i'm using a pictureBox and see nothing.

Comment: Roman could you maybe somehow connect to me or see my whole code in my new form i did ?

Comment: Roman this is the code in my new form: http://pastebin.com/YiwaWaMA and in form1 i just added a button click and make instance and show to the new form: Elgato_Video_Capture evc = new Elgato_Video_Capture();
            evc.Show();

Comment: You are set up well: you know the API and you have the inspiring code snippet. The minor things are for you to figure out, StackOverflow addresses questions/answers, not conversations.